# Fibonacci Sequence with user inputting first 2 numbers

Tags: c, arrays, fibonacci

I am writing a C program to get Fibonacci number, the user needs to put the first 2 numbers and the sequence starts from there. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    int i, input[MAX_SIZE];

    printf("please Enter first 2 digit of the Sequence\n");

    scanf("%d, %d" , &input[0], &input[1]);

    for (i = 2; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        input[i] = input[i-2] + input[i-1];

     printf("%d\n", input[i]);
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

But when i run the code with a input 2 and 3, I get a output like this `1499141456`, which is clearly not the sequence. please help.

Comment: is it better now? i don't understant what you ment by removing comma, i am getting 2 inputs from user.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf`.  If it's not 2, then it did not read two numbers, and the ones it didn't read are undefined (and could be anything).  Your `scanf` format is `%d, %d`, which means it is requiring a comma between the two numbers.  If you don't enter a comma when prompted, it will not parse the second number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the result in your code is bigger that the maximum value an `int` can handle

[Live example here!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b734a508d1650181)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647#In_computing)

> The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFF,FFFF<sub>16</sub>) is the maximum
>   positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer in computing. It is
>   therefore the maximum value for variables declared as integers (e.g.,
>   as `int`) in many programming languages, and the maximum possible score,
>   money, etc. for many video games.

Here's where it goes wrong

```
[...]
433494437 + 701408733 = 1134903170
701408733 + 1134903170 = 1836311903
1134903170 + 1836311903 = -1323752223
```

Answer (score 1):

When you exit from the loop `i` is equal to `MAX_SIZE`

```
printf("%d\n", input[i]);
```

you are printing a value outside of the bounds of the array (`input[MAX_SIZE]`).

Comment: `input[size]` isn't just uninitialized, it's unallocated -`input` goes from `0` to `size-1`

Comment: @Steve, oops, the question was edited after this answer, but you are right

Answer (score 0):

put print statement inside for loop braces.

```
or (i = 2; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
    input[i] = input[i-2] + input[i-1];
    printf("%d\n", input[i]);
    }
```

Comment: okay so i added the print statement inside the loop i am getting output something like this : 1280719746
1416505600
-1597741950
-181236350

Comment: and remove comma between %d,%d in scanf and make it as scanf("%d%d" , &input[0], &input[1]);